# How to reinstall a theme?

Tags: themes

My ambiance theme was corrupted but I can't figure out how to fix it or reinstall it. (Also I can't find it on the web to reinstall it). What do I do to fix it?

Comment: I think the package is called [`light-themes`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=light-themes). Please try purging and reinstalling.

Comment: okay I tried to do that but for some reason my problem wasn't fixed which is so strange!?!?

Comment: If you switch to other themes like Adwaitha or Radiance, does the corruption remain?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall by following Command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall light-themes
```

---

When searched by  `apt-cache search ambiance`:

```
light-themes - Light Themes (Ambiance and Radiance)
ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme - Qt Components for Ubuntu - Ubuntu Theme
focuswriter - Fullscreen distraction-free writing program
themecolorizer - Application for recoloring themes
```

This will help to install/remove packages related to themes.

Comment: ...so you're saying I should also reinstall those packages too? (`ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme` and the others?)

Comment: @MinaMichael After reinstalling only `light-themes` problem solved?

Comment: no sadly :( I'm really confused